# File uploading/handling in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have worked on this for 3 days straight and I'm at my wit's end.  I need someone to explain the literal step-by-step of what exactly is happening in this process and what the actual data is (or looks like) at each step.

I have a model with an ImageField() inside of it.  I have a form based on that model.  I pass the form to a template, that template passes the completed form data to a view.  I then bind the request.FILES data to an instance of the model/form, and save it.

What I want to do is use this uploaded file as a profile picture for my users, and I'd like to resize it prior to it being saved into the model.

After I've validated the data, I am passing the request.FILES['file'] data into a function and inside of this function PIL opens the data.  It opens it fine, every single time I have no issue with PIL seeing this data directly from the InMemory file.  However, I cannot get PIL to output this edited data into what Django is looking for in its ImageField().  I basically want to take this uploaded data, resize it, rename it and then save it through the ImageField() and let Django handle it from there.

The view:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    user_form = EditUserProfile(request.POST, instance=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id))
    siteprofile_form = EditSiteProfile(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=SiteProfile.objects.get(user=request.user))
    if user_form.is_valid() and siteprofile_form.is_valid():
        user_form.save()
        temp_siteprofile = siteprofile_form.save(commit=False)
        temp_siteprofile.profile_image = process_image_string(request.FILES['profile_image'], (100, 100))
        temp_siteprofile.save()
        return user_profile(request, request.user.username)
```

The function:

```
def process_image_string(f, size):
    f_image = Image.open(f)
    f_image = f_image.resize(size)
    output = StringIO()
    f_image.save(output, "JPEG")
    return output
```

Please keep in mind the function has changed probably 100 times in the last 3 days, this was (in my eyes) my closest success.

Comment: could you please provide the error that the above code throws ?

Comment: 'cStringIO.StringO' object has no attribute '_committed'

Answer (score 1):

Consider giving `django-stdimage` a try. It is an extension of `ImageField` and will resize the image for you, here's an example snippet:

```
class MyClass(models.Model):
    image1 = StdImageField(upload_to='path/to/img') # works as ImageField
    image2 = StdImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', blank=True) # can be deleted through admin
    image3 = StdImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', size=(640, 480)) # resizes image to maximum size to fit a 640x480 area
    image4 = StdImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', size=(640, 480, True)) # resizes image to 640x480 croping if necessary

    image_all = StdImageField(upload_to='path/to/img', blank=True, size=(640, 480), thumbnail_size=(100, 100, True)) # all previous features in one declaration
```

With this, you can save your ModelForm `EditUserProfile` directly, and you will not need to perform any image manipulation yourself. The downside is that this library uses PIL specifically.

Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/django-stdimage/

Github: https://github.com/humanfromearth/django-stdimage

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.  I will give this a shot.  However, I really want to learn from this experience so I can get better.